# If Statement in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom WordPress panel for my posts which I am referencing with this

```
$service = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'service', true);
```

I'm trying to insert some HTML that says:

```
if ($service == 1) {
  echo "Water Damage";
}
if ($service == 2) {
  echo "Fire Damage";
}
```

and so on. This part is not working. If I simply print the results of `$service`, that will display the appropriate numerical value, but I can't get the above to work.

Comment: Have you tried var_dump($service);

Comment: Can you please run `var_dump($service);` and update your question to include the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm right on this, the problem is that you are addressing `$service` as an int.

Have a look in the codex (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) , and you'll see that if the third Parameter is **false** it'll return an array of values, and if it's **true** (like in you case) it'll returns a **string**.

In the example above you where trying to compare a string to an int. try to do this instead:

```
if($service == '1'){
   echo "Water Damage";
}elseif($service == '2'){
   echo "Fire Damage";
}
```